# Tcp packet of 60 bytes sent with no data

Tags: tcp, wireshark

My application connects to the server using TCP and system is working fine. Using Wireshark I noticed that some TCP packets of 60 bytes are sent with no data. Is this normal?

as part of TCP transmissions and handshake are there some packets sent with no data?

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: Are those packages sent with IPv4 or IPv6 adresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the `ACK` packets that carry no data and only acknowledge received data. When using Wireshark it should display these "flags" on the empty packets.

To be more accurate you should show a screenshot of the wireshark capture, so we know what the size you mean is.
Meanwhile I dissected an ACK packet of IPv4 TCP traffic here and these are my results:

```
    Protocol           Size        Description
Ethernet protocol    14 byte    2 MAC adresses (6 byte), Protocoll type (2 byte)
Internet protocol    20 byte    The default header size
      TC protocol    32 byte    The default header size (20 byte) + options (12 byte)
_____________________________________________________________________________________
            Total    66 byte
       without EP    52 byte    (Probably the size the OP is talking about)
 without EP, Opts    40 byte    (The size talked about in the comments)
```

The options in my case were 2 NOPs (each 1 byte) and two timestamps (each 5 byte??). The order of the protocols is the same as in Wireshark.

Wireshark splits the information down to each field, so you can see what takes up how much space.

Comment: I don't see why an ACK packet would be 60 bytes though, should be 40 surely?

Comment: IPv4 TCP packages are allowed to bear an options field, that can take up to 40 bytes. The minimum header size (without the options) is 20 bytes, so this neatly adds up to 60 bytes.

Comment: But I don't see why a simple ACK packet would have any options at all.

Comment: There is for example the selective ACK that is solved via options on the ACK packets. One could argue that this is not a simple ACK packet. I think the best would be if the OP could supply the original data so no guesses must be made.

Comment: The next packet after this pure ACK packet, has the same SEQ number as this one, right?

Comment: @WindChaser: I am not sure what you are asking but it does not seem to be related to the this question/answer. If you cannot find the answer to your question, then ask a real question instead of writing a comment on a barely related answer.